# java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect while launching Firefox through GeckoDriver

Tags: selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, geckodriver

I have downloaded the latest version of Firefox ie Quantum. For Selenium,earlier there was no need of downloading any executable for Firefox to open an URL but now it throws an error of setting property for GeckoDriver.

So, I downloaded the latest version of **geckodriver-v0.20.1-arm7hf.tar.gz** and put that in `System.setProperty()` so it has thrown an error of connection refusal.

So, I used the alternative for opening the URL on Chrome. Downloaded chromeExecutable and was able to open without any connection refusal.

Code snippet:-

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\XYZ\\XXXX\\Downloads\\geckodriver-v0.20.1-arm7hf.tar.gz");
    WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("https://google.com");
```

Console Error:

```
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
```

Can anyone please help to figure out the issue on Mozilla Firefox?

Thanks 
Mehak

Comment: can you provide the code snippet here please

Comment: It will better if you write your sample code and StackStrees when you post the question. [How to ask question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There aren't a lot of infos in your question, but I guess the following is an issue:

In

> System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\XYZ\XXXX\Downloads\geckodriver-v0.20.1-arm7hf.tar.gz");

seems you are under a Windows OS (analyzing the path) but you are setting **geckodriver-v0.20.1-arm7hf.tar.gz**.

If you have a windows os, you should:

1. Download from [here](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) the related version (geckodriver-v0.20.1-win64.zip or geckodriver-v0.20.1-win32.zip, it depends on your OS)
2. Extract it and set, in the System.setProperty, the path to the extracted **geckodriver.exe**

Something like that:

> System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver",
>   "C:\XYZ\XXXX\Downloads\geckodriver.exe");

If you are under another os, you should download the proper asset and do basically the same thing. If you hava a linux/mac os, you have to be sure that the extracted geckodriver is executable.

Comment: Nice catch and great analysis

Comment: @DebanjanB Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

As per the *Best Practices* you need to follow the points below:

- Always use the latest released [**Selenium Java Client**](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/)
- Always use the latest released *WebDriver* binaries as per your relevant underlying OS from:

  - **GeckoDriver** : [mozilla/geckodriver](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases)
  - **ChromeDriver** : [ChromeDriver - WebDriver for Chrome](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads)
  - **IEDriverServer** : [release.storage](http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html)

As you are on *Windows OS* download either **geckodriver-v0.20.1-win32.zip** or **geckodriver-v0.20.1-win64.zip** and unzip for your usage.

- Always keep your *Browsers* updated with the latest releases (Firefox, Chrome, IE)
- In the `System.setProperty()` line the *Value* field should end with the name of the *WebDriver* variant as:

  - **Windows** :

    ```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\XYZ\\XXXX\\Downloads\\geckodriver.exe");
    ```
  - **Linux** :

    ```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "/opt/XYZ/XXXX/geckodriver");
    ```
  - **MacOSX** :

    ```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "/Users/XYZ/XXXX/geckodriver");
    ```

Comment: Thank you.. The issue was with geckodriver.exe only.Its resolved now

Comment: @mehak Upvote the answer if this/any answer is/was helpful to you for the future readers